# Simple Normalizing Text Example Does Not Work

Tags: java, unicode

I am trying to decompose some text.  Example from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html

```
  U+00C1    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE (Á)
```

or as two separate characters (the "decomposed" form):

```
  U+0041    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
  U+0301    COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
```

I am following this tutorial page from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html

This simple case does not work for me:

- Original word: `"schön"`
- NFC: `"schön"`
- NFD: `"scho\u0308n"`
- NFKC: `"schön"`
- NFKD: `"scho\u0308n"`

In all cases above, the function `Normalizer.normalize("schön", form)` (where form is one of `Normalizer.Form.NFC`, `Normalizer.Form.NFD`, etc.), the result is the same: `"schön"`

This code does not work on my Oracle JDK 1.6 or 1.7 installations on Linux, using in Eclipse JDT.

```
String n = Normalizer.normalize("schön", Normalizer.Form.NFD);
```

Result `n` is always "schön".

This "problem" smells like either (1) I completely misunderstand this function, or (2) a bad environment.  I am stuck.  Any suggestions?  My system setup is pretty vanilla as it goes.

Comment: "denormalize is the wrong term. It would imply the result would not be in a normal form. "decompose" or "normalize to NFD" are correct.

Comment: How are you testing the result? Printing doesn't count. Strings in NFD are canonically equivalent to the same string in NFC. Canonically equivalent strings are required to be treated as the same string by the implementation, and printing them out won't reveal the difference. You need to look at the characters individually. Here's an example that exposes the differences by showing the strings have different lengths: https://ideone.com/RzSp6Y

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: You are right about denorm vs decomp.  I updated my text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit is due to @R.MartinhoFernandes.  I was not aware the result will be canonically equivalent to the input.  I learned something new about Unicode de/composition today.

In short:

```
String.valueOf('Á').equals(String.valueOf('\u00C1'))
String.valueOf('A').equals(String.valueOf('\u0041'))
```

And:

```
Normalizer.normalize("Á", Normalizer.Form.NFD).equals("\u0041\u0301")
!String.valueOf('Á').equals("\u0041\u0301")
```

But:

```
System.out.println("Á\u0041\u0301")
```

Will print:

```
ÁÁ
```

Comment: I also found extra useful examples in http://info.michael-simons.eu/2013/01/25/hidden-java-gems-java-text-normalizer/.

Answer (score 3):

just do this, it will do the job:

```
String n = Normalizer.normalize("schön", Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
```

Comment: what is "this" doing? what is the "job"

Comment: @UmNyobe It will replace all Unicode special chars with their "non-special" equivalent, so, "ö" will become "o".